# Referring or passing variables within YAML file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml

I have the below sample YAML configuration. I'm trying to refer variables within same YAML file as below:

```yaml
    appname : delta 
    configrepo : dev
    development:
        clusterurl : "/sa1/demo/dfn"
        email: pseudo@my-fdn.com
        mount_dir: /mnt/tigers
        app_config_dir: "/opt/tigers/$appname/$configrepo/svcaccount"
```

After reading YAML through Groovy into `vardict` when I try to do `echo '$vardict.app_config_dir'` I'm getting the values as below:

```
/opt/tigers///svcaccount
```

I'm looking for desired output as below:

```
/opt/tigers/delta/dev/svcaccount
```

Kindly suggest the correct way of referring the variables within single YAML file.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the Groovy script to your question. Which parameter type ist this in your Jenkins project?

Comment: @marc, you have to develop this behavior. one of the options to use SimpleTemplateEngine